# binding controller object to a component in ember

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to build a modal box component in ember. The modal box has two standard buttons, "close" and "save". I wanted to pass controller action to this component so that when save button is clicked, it calls the controller action that was passed. I call my component as :

```
 {{#affi-modal-box title="Test title" modalId="createNewAnalyticsRunModal" controllerBinding=controller}}some message{{/affi-modal-box}}
```

and my component :

```
AS.AffiModalBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
attributeBindings: ['modelId','test'],
    //this is the function that gets called when save button is clicked 
    onSaveButtonClick : function(){

        console.log(this.controllerFor('analysisTemplates'));//fails
        console.log(this.get('controller'));//returns modal box component which I don't need 
    }
```

});

Any ideas how I can pass the controller object to the component??

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The way Ember.Component's work is to be agnostic to other parts of your application, therefore rather then passing in a controller on which you want an action to be called on when something happens in your component, you do it more like in this way:

```
{{#affi-modal-box 
  title="Test title" 
  modalId="createNewAnalyticsRunModal" 
  action="actionNameOnTheController"}}some message{{/affi-modal-box}}
```

As you can see you set the `action` attribute to the action name on your controller, and then inside your component you simply call `this.sendAction('action');` which will trigger whatever action name you defined earlier:

```
AS.AffiModalBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['modelId','test'],
  //this is the function that gets called when save button is clicked 
  onSaveButtonClick : function(){
    this.sendAction('action');
  }
});
```

So now, whenever `onSaveButtonClick` is invoked it will send the action `actionNameOnTheController` to whatever controller is listening to it. And best of all, without knowing nothing about the controller. This is the kind of functionality that makes Ember.Component's reusable in any way.

Please see here a [simple demo](http://jsbin.com/aDarIRo/2/edit) of the concept explained.

Hope it helps.

Comment: But if you're just trying to update a controller property from within a component, you just reassign the value of that property from within the component, and the automatic bindings from having passed a controller property into a component will take care of the updates, right? So for simple controller property changes, you don't need to use this primary action way. Is it more the ember way to do so even for simple property changes?

Comment: @ahnbizcad if you're going to couple the component with the controller that tightly, you might as well not even use a component. The purpose of components is decoupling for reusability. So the component is built with actions that act as hooks. And depending on where the component is dropped in, those actions can trigger different controller actions to do what is most useful in that context. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @intuitivepixel can we pass parameters with this solution ?